# ¿porque no puedo mostrar en mi pagina web la lista de productos comprados?

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una pagina ecommerce, quiero hacer que al apretar el boton "comprar" en el producto, aparezca en la parte superior derecha del nav, la lista de productos y que el usuario lo vea.

Aclaracion: el codigo es muy extenso, puse las partes escensiales para resolver este problema.

El primer boton es de comprar, el segundo es el contenedor. (aclaracion: El HTML y javascript fueron hechos en sus respectivos documentos, no estan en el mismo documento)

```
1.<button id="btnComprar-" class="boton-comprar">Comprar</button>
2.<div id="carrito-contedor" class="carrito-contenedor"></div>

class Carrito {
  constructor() {
    this.carrito = [];
    this.total = 0;
  }

  
//Aca esta el problema, esta es la parte que deberia mostrar mi lista de productos comprados pero no lo hace.
    const renderizarCarrito = (carritoLista) => {
      const carritoContenedorHTML = document.getElementById('carrito-contenedor')

      if(this.carrito.length >= 1){
          carritoContenedorHTML.innerHTML += `
            modelo:${carritoLista.modelo} x  Precio:${carritoLista.precio}
          `
        }else{
          carritoContenedorHTML.innerHTML = "El Carrito esta vacio"
      }   
    }
  }
}

const carrito = new Carrito();


 


/*---------Aca empieza el problema-------*/

          carrito.renderizarCarrito(producto)/*ACA LLAMO A LA FUNCION, pero el error en el navegador es el siguiente: Uncaught TypeError: carrito.renderizarCarrito is not a function*/

          console.log(carrito);
      })
    })
  })

renderizarProductos(productos);
```

Como puedo solucionar este problema.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) la comunidad, por favor oprime [edit] y agrega el mínimo código necesario para reproducir el problema. Te recomiendo utilizar un `fragmento Javascript/HTML/CSS`, es el séptimo botón o puedes abrirlo al presionar `Ctrl M`.

Answer (score 2):

Las palabras reservadas `const`, `let` y `var` definen un contexto (un alcance) de la variable. Cuando trabajas con clases el contexto de las variables y funciones siempre está limitado a la clase misma, por lo que no es necesario ocupar esos asignadores

En palabras simple elimina el `const` de tu función `renderizarCarrito`

---

En otros lenguajes decentes es perfectamente posible declarar una constante dentro de una clase y tiene mucho sentido. A mi parecer esto se debe a javascript es un lenguaje parchaeado, en el cual se han ido agregando especificaciones sobre la marcha para corregir problemas que nunca debieron existir en su diseño inicial

Para declarar algo parecido a una constante, es decir que no se pueda sobrescribir su valor, se debe hacer algo como

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'staticProp', {
    writable: 'false'
});
```

Pero no hay forma de hacer esto desde la clase misma, usando la notación de clases.

Answer (score 2):

En complemento a la respuesta que te dieron otra forma en que un objeto o array pueda hacerse inmutable (no se pueden cambiar los valores, ni agregar nuevos) lo más parecido que veo a una constante, es usar Object.freeze() [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

```
class Myclass{
  constructor(){
    this.myconstobj = {name: 'michael', age: 31}
    Object.freeze(this.myconstobj)
    this.myarray = [1,2,3,4,5]
    Object.freeze(this.myarray)
  }
}

let obj = new Myclass();

obj.myconstobj.name = 'richard' // aunque nos deje reasignar, en realidad las propiedades no han cambiado
obj.myconstobj.age = 52
console.log(obj.myconstobj) 

obj.myarray.push(6) 
console.log(obj.myarray) // Cannot add property 5, object is not extensible
```

Esto obviamente tiene limitaciones, no puedo cambiar las propiedades internas ni agregar nuevas, pero lo que sí puedo hacer es reasignar el objeto entero.